# Adding Widevine DRM support in my player

Tags: android, drm

I am creating a video player, which can play widevine video content.
I found the following streams

Stream 1: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/sintel_main_720p_4br_tp.wvm

Stream 2: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/starz_main_720p_6br_tp.wvm

Is it require for me to have CWIP membership to add widevine support?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to play those streams? If yes then please help me. What I have to do to play widevine video contents? I mean ids, keys or anything else.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are asking here. Your best bet is to read the Widevine CWP intro on this topic: http://www.widevine.com/cwip/index.html

If you are asking whether you need to be a CWIP member to package content for viewing with Widevine protection, the answer is no. There are a number of companies that provide that service. Search for Widevine encoding services.

If you are asking whether you need to be a CWIP member to integrate Widevine playback on your device, it depends on the device, but probably not. Widevine is integrated in a number of places and you should check the Widevine site. See the link above.

You **would** need to be a CWIP member if you are planning to setup your own license server that serves licenses to Widevine players.